# iScroll 4 - cancel preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, events, touch, iscroll4

In the code below I added three comments that should explain what the question is. In short: I'm wondering how to disable `e.preventDefault();` when it's already set?

```
   var startY;
   myScroll = new iScroll(DOMElement, {
        snap: 'li',
        bounce: false,
        bounceLock: false,
        momentum: false,
        hScrollbar: false,
        vScrollbar: false,
        hScroll: true,
        vScroll: false,
        wheelAction: 'scroll',
        onBeforeScrollStart: function(e){
            startY = e.pageY;
            // By default it's advisable to disable browser's scroll
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        onScrollStart: function(){  },
        onScrollMove: function(e){
            // But here I want to enable browser's functionality if user
            // explicitly demands this (i.e. tries to scroll vertically)
            if(startY >= e.pageY+70 || startY <= e.pageY-70){
                console.log('test');
                //alert('test');
                console.log(e);
                // However, I don't know how to restore this functionality
                // Touch device detects 'test' alert correctly and this is
                // where I'm stuck.
            }
        },
        onScrollEnd: function(){ },
        onRefresh: function(){ },
        onDestroy: function(){ },
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can control scrolling in `onBeforeScrollStart`. Prevent scrolling between specific area. If it exceeds, scroll starts. I think this helps:

```
var startY;
var isStarted = false;
myScroll = new iScroll(DOMElement, {
    snap: 'li',
    bounce: false,
    bounceLock: false,
    momentum: false,
    hScrollbar: false,
    vScrollbar: false,
    hScroll: true,
    vScroll: false,
    wheelAction: 'scroll',
    onBeforeScrollStart: function(e){
        var y=e.pageY;
        if (!isStarted) {
            startY = y + 0;
            isStarted = true;
        }

        if(startY < y+70 || startY > y-70){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    onScrollStart: function(){  },
    onScrollMove: function(e){ },
    onScrollEnd: function(){
        isStarted = false;
    },
    onRefresh: function(){ },
    onDestroy: function(){ },
});
```

Comment: I tried this in `onScrollMove` but once `preventDefault` happened, it doesn't ever want to return to browser functionality.

Comment: Thank you for updated solution! It can't work because we can't detect whether user will want to scroll vertically (and regain browser's functionality) or not. It's like in "App Store" on iPhone - you can scroll horizontally but after certain amount of pixels (top/down) you regain vertical scrolling as well. I need exactly this functionality and this can be detected only on `move` event if I'm not mistaken :) User scrolls carousel horizontally and when he doesn't want to scroll further he must regain browser's vertical scrolling as well (but `preventDefault` blocks it and thus users is stuck).